# Get string method returning null when word is definitely not null

Tags: java, string, null

I am writing a hangman game, and for some reason my `getW()` method is returning null when it should be returning a string that is certainly not null.  I have extensively added `System.out.println`s to make sure that `word` is staying the same.  It seems to be the same everywhere but in the `getW()` method, which is why `getW()` is returning null.

This is my code:

Hangman.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Hangman extends JPanel{
    private String word;

    public void setupLayout(JFrame window){
        window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        HangmanArea panel1 = new HangmanArea();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        window.add(panel1, c);

        GuessedLetters panel2 = new GuessedLetters();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        window.add(panel2, c);

        Letters panel3 = new Letters();
        panel3.setBackground(Color.black);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        window.add(panel3, c);
        System.out.println("Before repaint: "+ word);
        panel1.callRepaint();
        panel2.callRepaint();
        panel3.callRepaint();
        System.out.println("After repaint: " + word);
    }

    public void startWindow(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenHeight = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        int windowHeight = (int) ((screenHeight / 4) * 3);
        window.setSize(windowHeight, windowHeight);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setupLayout(window);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void startGame(){
        Prep prepare = new Prep();
        word = prepare.findWord(true);
        System.out.println("Word found: " + word);
        startWindow();
        System.out.println("Word is unchanged: " + word);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Hangman start = new Hangman();
        start.startGame();
    }
    public String getW(){
        System.out.println("getW()'s word: " + word);    //At this point, word is null
        return word;
    }
}
```

Letters.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Letters extends JPanel {
    private String word = "aaa";
    public void callRepaint(){
        Hangman object = new Hangman();
        word = object.getW();
        System.out.println("Word for Letters: " + word);
        repaint();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("letters", 50, 50);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this seems like a lot of code, but Hangman.java and Letters.java are the two important classes.  Prep.java's `findWord()` method just takes a random word from a wordlist and returns it. I don't think it's necessary to post that, but I can. GuessedLetters.java and HangmanArea.java are completely empty except for the `callRepaint()` and `paintCompnent(Graphics g)` methods.  I can post them if you need, but I don't think they are very important.

The output could looks like this:

```
Word found: night
Before repaint: night
getW()'s word: null
Word for Letters: null
After repaint: night
Word is unchanged: night
```

I have no idea what's causing this.

Comment: Why is `callRepaint` creating a new instance of `Hangman`? obviously it won't have the correct `word` assigned, as it is not the same as your main object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing the object that has the `word` variable initialized (to "night" in the example output you posted) to the `callRepaint` method, instead creating a new instance inside that method (which is not connected to your "main" object). Instead you should either pass in the object as parameter, e.g.:

```
public void callRepaint(Hangman object){
        word = object.getW();
        System.out.println("Word for Letters: " + word);
        repaint();
}
```

and call it like this inside your `Hangman` class:

```
panel1.callRepaint(this);
panel2.callRepaint(this);
panel3.callRepaint(this);
```

or probably just pass the `String`, e.g.:

```
public void callRepaint(String word){
        System.out.println("Word for Letters: " + word);
        repaint();
}
```

and call it this way:

```
panel1.callRepaint(getW());
panel2.callRepaint(getW());
panel3.callRepaint(getW());
```

Comment: Thank you.  This has been annoying me for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

In callRepaint you create a new Hangman object, whose `word` member is never initialized.

Either you declare your word variable static, meaning that every instance of Hangman will share this variable (it's not a class member anymore and this is a bad coding style) or you add the original Hangman instance as a parameter during instantiation of the Letters class or during calling callRepaint. Or you set the word member of Hangman as a parameter during Letters instantiation.